# Argument with space throught command line node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've done script like

**"script:addsomething":"node ./myScript.js 'sometheng with space'"**

If i am running it just like

**node ./myScript.js 'sometheng with space'** in powershell

it's work and I've got line in process.argv like  'sometheng with space'

But If i am running it like

**npm run script:addsomething**

i've got three line in process.argv
How Can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

can you try

```
"script:addsomething":"node ./myScript.js \"sometheng with space\""
```